# Why synchronized_value was not added to C++17/C++20?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, mutex, c++20

I am a bit confused on the status of synchronized_value, on one hand it is suggested in CppCoreGuidelines, but on the other it is not available in C++20, there is not even a boost version (there is an experimental one).

Note: I know standardization takes time, but the paper is from 2014.

I am mostly concerned if there were some issues discovered during standardization process, so synchronized_value should not be used, contrary to Core Guidelines.

> CP.50: Define a `mutex` together with the data it guards. Use
> `synchronized_value<T>` where possible
>
> Reason: It should be obvious to a reader that the data is to be guarded and how. This decreases the chance of the wrong mutex being locked, or the mutex not being locked.
>
> Using a `synchronized_value<T>` ensures that the data has a mutex, and
> the right mutex is locked when the data is accessed. See the WG21
> [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0290r2.html) to add `synchronized_value` to a future TS or revision of the
> C++ standard.

Comment: Proposal is still under development I think see https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/255

Comment: GCC 13 has an implementation of `std::experimental::synchronized_value`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason it wasn't added to C++17 and C++20 is because it wasn't ready yet.

There were a number of revisions to the proposal as it went through the standardization process. It was voted into the Concurrency v2 working paper in 2023, and is present in the [N4953 Concurrency TS working draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/n4953.pdf).

I am unaware of any plans to add it to a future version of the C++ standard, but I imagine that will happen eventually. For now, you need an implementation of that part of the Concurrency TS v2 (e.g. GCC 13 has it).